# Selenium c# Find element exist on a page using Pagefactory

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, page-factory

I am migrating my selenium scripts to PageFactory and currently stuck with find if an element exist on the page

My current implementation is

```
public bool IsElementExist(string element)
        {
            try
            {
                Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(element));
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

My page has multiple items on its basket and if I need to delete all/some of the item. Everytime I delete the page refreshes, but the Pagefactory FindsBy is not getting refreshed and retains the very first value. Any assistance please.

Comment: Did you try loading the Page Object (PageFactory.initElements) again?

Comment: Yeah, tried it. But since the PageFactory.initElements runs before the page refresh, its still failing. I wont be able to use new WebdriverWait(driver,waittime).Until<> condition as the page element exists all the time

Comment: Can you update the Question with all the relevant code blocks related to `PageFactory.initElements` & `WebdriverWait(driver,waittime)`, Page Object  etc.

Comment: while(!NoAddressExistMsg.Text.Equals("There are currently no addresses stored."))
            {
                DeleteDefaultAddress.Click();
                ConfirmAddressDeletePopup.Click();

 new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName("c-address-book__header")));
               
                PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
            }

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple elements matching a given locator, the findElement() method simply picks the first one and returns the corresponding WebElement. This could be confusing sometimes, because you might interact with a different element unintentionally.

A slightly better implementation of your function would be as below (example in Java but works similarly in C#):

```
    public Boolean objectExists(By by) {
        int numberOfMatches = driver.findElements(by).size();       
        if(numberOfMatches == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // 0 matches OR more than 1 match
            return false;   
        }
    }
```

Not sure if this is directly related to your issue, but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, but Sorry, I am looking to have an implementation using Pagefactory FindsBy.. Not this one. IList<IWebment> .count would do the same. that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Below I am performing a wait but it provides an example of how you can pass an IWebElement to find an object and perform an action. The method you provided is going to expect you to provide the XPath as a string rather than the name of an already identified element on the page.

```
// Wait Until Object is Clickable
    public static void WaitUntilClickable(IWebElement elementLocator, int timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(DriverUtil.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            waitForElement.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elementLocator));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element with locator: '" + elementLocator + "' was not found in current context page.");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This lives in a BaseUtil.cs that I call from MyPageFunctionality.cs like this:

```
BaseUtil.WaitUntilClickable(btnLogin, 10);
```

Comment: From where do you call it from exactly?

Comment: Using POM C# TDD: I use DriverUtil to house my driver, BaseUtil to house common functionality, Pages to house page objects and functionality respective to page, and Test Classes to combine functionalities of the pages into a flow of automatable tasks. I would call BaseUtil.WaitUntilClickable(objAsDefinedInPageObjClass, timeoutInSeconds) from within a given page function to slow down a particular action being performed rather than in a test to slow down test execution. If I know I'm going to have to wait on a given obj, then my wait needs to be in the handling of that obj not in my test.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
  //call the method and pass the xpath. You can also create css, id etc. 

  page.WaitForElementNoLongerDisplayed_byXpath("//div[contains(@class, 'my-error-message')]");



   public static void WaitForElementNoLongerDisplayed_byXpath(string elementXpath)
    {
        try
        {
            _wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElements(By.XPath(elementXpath)).Count == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            LogFunctions.WriteError("Element is still displayed and should not be");
            TakeScreenshot("elementStillShown");
            throw;
        }
    }
```